# Not able to access firebase DB with custom token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

For some reason when I test my DB access rules it works well on the firebase simulator. But when I try it on my code it does not work, the value never returns. If I change the rules to allow global read like bellow the code start working again.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read":"true"
   }
}
```

So I believe that the error is not in the rules themselves but in some point during the authentication. The weirdest part is that when I run

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
```

it returns the expected value

```
"0x17d54a755b1bccbe23c6834a38f511c055e67a71"
```

I already checked the docs

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

But I didn't manage to find the problem

These are the access rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "NFC":{
      "$mainProductKey":{
        ".write":"root.child('brands').child(auth.uid).child($mainProductKey).exists()"
      },
      ".write":"root.child('brands').child(auth.uid).child('products').exists()",
      ".read":"true"
    },
    "brands":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

this is part of my DB structure

```
{
  "NFC" : {
    ...
  },
  "brands" : {
    "0x17d54A755b1BCcBe23C6834A38F511c055e67a71" : {
      "unlocked" : true
    }
  }
}
```

this is my JWT token payload

```
{
  "uid": "0x17d54a755b1bccbe23c6834a38f511c055e67a71",
  "iat": 1536771364,
  "exp": 1536774964,
  "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
  "iss": "firebase-adminsdk-u3222@deverytest-3d280.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "firebase-adminsdk-u3222@deverytest-3d280.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

this is the code that is not returning after I added the rules

```
export function loadAccountLock (brandAddress) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`brands/${brandAddress}/`).once('value', function (snapshot) {
      let brand = snapshot.val() || {}
      resolve(!!brand.unlocked)
    })
  })
}
```

and this is how I'm authenticating the users

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the the problem was. Actually I was sending the lower case Ethereum address inside the token, but the keys that I had on my DB where the uppercase ones. As the firebase rules are case sensitive I was getting the read permission Denied.

> In short there was no problem with the rules or with the auth code